# Optimal transport code (Scipy linear programming optimization) takes much longer time

Tags: scipy, linear-programming

I have been trying to compute the Wasserstein distance between two one dimensional Gaussian distributions with mean 0.0 and 4.0, with variances 9.0 and 16.0 respectively. I used scipy.linprog.optimize module and used the "interior-point" method as said in the following link
https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/10/scipy-linear-programming-large-but-easy.html.
However, it takes more than 17 hours, and still (my code is )running to run solve 300 x 300 LP matrix problems (i.e) 300 source nodes and 300 destination nodes. However, the document says it could be possible to solve the problem with 1000 source nodes and 1000 destination nodes.(i.e) one can solve the LP problem with 1,000,000 (one million) decisive variables. What is wrong with my code? Why it takes such a long time? Do we need large memory (or clusters) to solve such problems?
my code

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import scipy

#Initializing the LP matrix
Piprob=np.zeros(500*500).reshape(500,500)

def Piprobmin(Krv,rhoi,rhoj):
  r1=np.shape(Krv)[0]
  r2=np.shape(Krv)[1]
  print("r1,r2",r1,r2)
  #Computing the LP Matrix which has just two ones in each column
  pmat=np.zeros((r1+r2)*(r1*r2)).reshape((r1+r2),(r1*r2))
  for i in range(r1+r2):
      for j in range(r1*r2):
          if((i<r1) and (j<((i+1)*r2)) and (j>=(i*r2))):
              pmat[i][j]=1
          if(i>=r1):
              for k in range(r1*r2):
                  if j==(i-r1)+(k*r2):
                      pmat[i][j]=1
  #flattening the cost matrix into one dimensional array
  krvf=Krv.flatten()
  tempr=np.append(rhoi,rhoj)
  Xv=[] #Creating list for joint probability matrix elements
                          
  res = scipy.optimize.linprog(c=krvf,method='interior-point',A_eq=pmat,b_eq=tempr,options= 
  {'sparse':True, 'disp':True})

  print("res=\n",res)
  wv=res.fun
  for  l1 in range(r1*r2):
      Xv.append(res.x[l1])
  Yv=np.array(Xv)
  Yv=Yv.reshape(r1,r2)
  #returning Yv-joint probability and ,Wv-minimized wasserstein distance
  return Yv,wv

  Piprob,W=Piprobmin(K,result1,result2) #K-cost function matrix,result1 is the first 
                                        #marginal,result2 is the second marginal
  end_time = datetime.now()
  print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

The size of the cost function is 300 X 300 and size, each marginal have 300 points (total 600 constraints). I verified my cost function is symmetric and non-negative. and each marginal is summed to one as they are just probabilities.

Comment: Probably better suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (and not a `machine-learning` question, tag removed).

Comment: @desertnaut If the code is still running, I'm not sure it will ever exit successfully. Which makes me doubt whether the code actually works, which is a requirement for CR.

Comment: @Mast Actually it gives results for 150 x 150 LP matrix. However, if I give 300 source and 300 destinations. it takes longer time

Comment: Ther is no loop in this code. Scipy linear programming module takes in the cost matrix, LP matrix and constraints and gives the optimized answer and matrix elements of joint probability

Comment: @Mast Since it *does* give results with a smaller matrix, I guess we can safely assume that the code works indeed

Comment: However, the link says it should work for 1 million variables. I am doubting whether it needs a larger RAM or anything. The blogger didn't say anything about the time.

Comment: The blog post details that you need to use **sparse matrices** and not dense, fully allocated ones. You may want to read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [blog post](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/10/scipy-linear-programming-large-but-easy.html) the word **sparse** is used many times. Not without reason. It is extremely important to store the A matrix as a sparse matrix. Otherwise, you will not be able to handle large problems. The blog post discusses the difference in memory requirements of the transportation LP matrix in great detail, so this point should have been hard to miss.

Here is some example code on how to set up a transportation model with 1000 source nodes and 1000 destination nodes using **scipy.optimize.linprog**. Again, the LP matrix has 2,000 rows and 1,000,000 columns and is **stored sparse**.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy.optimize as opt
from memory_profiler import profile


def GenerateData(M,N):
   np.random.seed(123)

   # form objective function
   c = np.random.uniform(0,10,(M,N))

   # demand, supply
   s = np.random.uniform(0,15,M)
   d = np.random.uniform(0,10,N)
   assert np.sum(d) <= np.sum(s), "supply too small"

   #print('c',c)
   #print('s',s)
   #print('d',d)
   return {'c':c, 's':s, 'd':d, 'n':N, 'm':M}

def FormLPData(data):

   rhs = np.append(data['s'],-data['d'])

   # form A
   # column (i,j)=n*i+j has two nonzeroes:
   #    1 at row i with rhs supply(i)
   #    1 at row N+j with rhs demand(j)
   N = data['n']
   M = data['m']
   NZ = 2*N*M
   irow = np.zeros(NZ, dtype=int)
   jcol = np.zeros(NZ, dtype=int)
   value = np.zeros(NZ)
   for i in range(N):
      for j in range(M):
         k = M*i+j
         k1 = 2*k
         k2 = k1+1
         irow[k1] = i
         jcol[k1] = k
         value[k1] = 1.0
         irow[k2] = N+j
         jcol[k2] = k
         value[k2] = -1.0

   A = sparse.coo_matrix((value, (irow, jcol)))

   #print('A',A)
   #print('rhs',rhs)

   return {'A':A,'rhs':rhs}



@profile
def run():
   # dimensions
   M = 1000  # sources
   N = 1000 # destinations
   data = GenerateData(M,N)
   lpdata = FormLPData(data)
   res = opt.linprog(c=np.reshape(data['c'],M*N),A_ub=lpdata['A'],b_ub=lpdata['rhs'],options={'sparse':True, 'disp':True})


if __name__ == '__main__':
   run()
```

So it looks like you totally missed the whole point about the blog post.